# Can't see view items in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to Android Studios and I am working on an application using fragments.
My code is ok and the build succed but the main fragment don't show some textViews and Buttons declared in InfosFragment.xml. MainActivity can switch between fragments with a container.
I don't know what to try.

**Fragment_infos.xml**

````
```    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infos"
        android:layout_width="197dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="219dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="634dp"
        android:text="@string/resInfos"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="686dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cnt"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pas_info" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        ...
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="@string/resTitreInformations"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/endButton"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        ...
        android:onClick="terminer"
        android:text="@string/resBoutonFin"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />    
```
````

**infosFragment.java**

````
```    public class InfosFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_infos, container, false);
    }
    @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Button bouton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.endButton);
        bouton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                terminer();
            }
        });
    }
    public void terminer()
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}    ```
````

**MainActivity.java**

````
```    package com.example.vlcapplicationvendeur;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       /*if(savedInstanceState.isEmpty())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }*/
        // création du switcher entre deux fragments
        BottomNavigationView bottomNv = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        bottomNv.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
        {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;

            switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav_infos:
                    selectedFragment = new InfosFragment();

                break;

                case R.id.nav_avis:
                    selectedFragment = new AvisFragment();

                break;

                case R.id.nav_tendance:
                    selectedFragment = new TendanceFragment();

                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

            return true;
        }
    };

}    ```
````

[what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYNCO.png)
[what I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCfIH.png)

Comment: Oops ! what are you saying? unable to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Layout is not showning because of some attributes you defined in your `TextView`:

```
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

You can try `LinearLayout` instead and then move to `RelativeLayout`.